# Does compiling NodeMCU with lots of modules have an impact on the memory usage?

Tags: memory, lua, ram, esp8266, nodemcu

Using the [cloud compiling website](https://nodemcu-build.com/) I created a custom NodeMCU firmware that has a lot of modules. So many that the firmware itself is almost 700KB in size. I usually only use up to 5 modules for a single project, so I'm wondering if the inclusion of all the other modules in the firmware have a noticeable negative impact on the RAM usage.

Comment: RAM usage and flash usage are two different things. Your firmware is saved in flash and parts of it may be temporarily loaded in IRAM (instruction RAM, as oppsed to DRAM, data RAM). When using the ESP-12F, you have 4 MB of flash memory available for you firmware. But fetching code from flash can be slow, thus the IRAM (64 KiB big). Everything else (heap & stack) is in DRAM (96 KiB). You cannot deduce the dynamic memory usage in DRAM from the size of your firmware (which occupies flash and parts of IRAM), you have to know what objects the module creates or statically allocates on the stack.

Comment: Okay, if I for instance include the `tmr` module in my build, then I can simply call `tmr.now()` any time I want. So I would assume that the tmr object/class is always loaded into the RAM. But maybe I'm wrong and the firmware only loads the module once I try to access tmr. I don't know.. Well, the reason why I asked this question is because it seems like the firmware itself occupies almost all of the RAM (once my Lua script is longer than around 300 lines, the script doesn't execute anymore and I get memory errors instead).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an excellent explanation of the ESP8266 memory map (and other interesting bits) at https://www.kickstarter.com/projects/214379695/micropython-on-the-esp8266-beautifully-easy-iot/posts/1501224. Furthermore, you got a great answer as a comment.

Every module baked into the binary consumes memory just by "being there". If you wanted to measure the impact a single module has on the available heap you'd have to build two binaries, one with and one without that module. You'd flash both and calculate the delta of running `node.heap()` right after start.

> Does compiling NodeMCU with lots of modules have an impact on the memory usage?

Yes, it definitely does as you noticed.

> I usually only use up to 5 modules for a single project

That's why we recommend to use a different set (read "minimal set") of modules for every project. The beauty of the NodeMCU firmware is that you only have to do this once, contrary to e.g. Arduino, after which swapping scripts or even individual functions in'n out is super quick.

I suggest you also take a look at https://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/dev/en/lua-developer-faq/#techniques-for-reducing-ram-and-spiffs-footprint. A major overhaul is in the making at https://github.com/nodemcu/nodemcu-firmware/pull/1899.